# "npm run dev" creates 0.js, 1.js, ... 14.js files in my public folder

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack, vuejs2

I'm a beginner using Webpack, NPM and VueJS.

I dont know what I did and I can't find any solution on internet.

When I run the command `npm run dev` in VueJS, webpack creates 15 files numbered from 0.js to 14.js

The files first lines are :

```
(window["webpackJsonp"] = window["webpackJsonp"] || []).push([[0],{
```

Where 0 in the file name

Anyone knows what I broke in my app ?

EDIT:

I figured out that every file is related to One component.
And I guess that this is in relation with my router file :

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(Router);

function loadView(view) {
    return () => import(`../components/${view}.vue`);
}

function loadLayout(view) {
    return () => import(`../components/_layouts/${view}.vue`);
}

const routes = [
    // USER ROUTES
    {
        path: '/dashboard',
        component: loadView('user/Dashboard'),
        meta: {
            layout: loadLayout('user/Layout'),
            auth: "user"
        },
        name: 'user'
    },
    // SUPPLIER ROUTES
    {
        path: '/supplier',
        component: loadView('supplier/Dashboard'),
        meta: {
            layout: loadLayout('supplier/Layout'),
            auth: "supplier"
        },
        name: 'supplier'
    },
    // ADMIN ROUTES
    {
        path: '/admin',
        component: loadView('admin/Dashboard'),
        meta: {
            layout: loadLayout('admin/Layout'),
            auth: "admin"
        },
        name: 'admin'
    },
    // DEFAULT ROUTES
    {
        path: '/register',
        component: loadView('auth/Register'),
        meta: {
            layout: loadLayout('home/Layout'),
            auth: false
        },
        name: 'register'
    },
    {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'login',
        component: loadView('auth/Login'),
        meta: {
            layout: loadLayout('home/Layout'),
            auth: false
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/',
        component: loadView('home/Home'),
        meta: {
            layout: loadLayout('home/Layout'),
            auth: undefined
        },
        name: 'home'
    },
    // otherwise redirect to home
    {
        path: '*',
        redirect: '/'
    }

];

Vue.router = new Router({
    hashbang: false,
    mode: 'history',
    routes
});

export default Vue.router;
```

Comment: Did you add dynamic imports? `import()`

Comment: I edited my post, yes I import dynamically my components

Comment: The integer filenames is the default behavior of `import()`. Google for "import() specify filename", you should see something like `/* webpackChunkName */`

Comment: The filenames aren't really a problem... the main issue is that they are all in my public folder and take a lot of space in there

Comment: Oh. Idk why they end up in the public folder, that shouldn't happen. Does that also happen when you `npm run build`?

Comment: Yes, it goes in the same path with `npm run build`

Comment: There is a way to inspect the vue cli webpack config, google for the `inspect` command, and search the output to find out why files are being sent to `public/`

Comment: The solution :
```mix.webpackConfig({     output: {         chunkFilename: 'js/[name].js',     }, });```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move those dynamic imports, you have to put this code in `webpack.mix.js` :

```
mix.webpackConfig({     
    output: {         
        chunkFilename: 'js/[name].js',     
    }, 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In large applications, we may need to divide the app into smaller chunks and only load a component from the server when it's needed. To make that possible, Vue has a defineAsyncComponent function:

```js
import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue'

const AsyncComp = defineAsyncComponent(() => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // ...load component from server
    resolve(/* loaded component */)
  })
})
// ... use `AsyncComp` like a normal component
```

As you can see, defineAsyncComponent accepts a loader function that returns a Promise.

As with normal components, async components can be registered globally using app.component():

```js
app.component('MyComponent', defineAsyncComponent(() =>
  import('./components/MyComponent.vue')
))
```

You can also use defineAsyncComponent when registering a component locally:

```
<script>
import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue'

export default {
  components: {
    AdminPage: defineAsyncComponent(() =>
      import('./components/AdminPageComponent.vue')
    )
  }
}
</script>
```

Whenever you access component that you use asynchronous components, you can check network tab on Development tool, you can see a lot of js files, start with `number`.js